# Is it possible to create a MySQL query like this?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. I would like to create a query which returns all rows from one table where the sum of the integer values from the column in the table is less than a specific value.

Imagine the tables were like:

`Accounts`:

```
USERID | STATUS | LAST_LOGIN_DATE | etc......
4594 . 1 . XX/XX/XX 00:00:00 . etc.....
2414 . 1 . XX/XX/XX 00:00:00 . etc.....
1894 . 1 . XX/XX/XX 00:00:00 . etc.....
```

`History`:

```
USERID | VALUE | DATE
4594 .   10000 . XX/XX/XX 00:00:00  
2414 .   10000 . XX/XX/XX 00:00:00  
1894 .   10000 . XX/XX/XX 00:00:00  
6974 .   10000 . XX/XX/XX 00:00:00  
3491 .   10000 . XX/XX/XX 00:00:00  
1590 .   10000 . XX/XX/XX 00:00:00  
6554 .   10000 . XX/XX/XX 00:00:00
```

I would want to `SELECT Accounts.* FROM Accounts` but on the condition that e.g. for each `userid` the `value` column is less than for example `30,000`. Is that possible in MySQL? Thanks.

Comment: There are not duplicates in `History`. So, what would be "the sum of the integer values"? Please be more concrete and edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention the `sum` of the column `value` to be less than 30000, right?

```
select a.*
from accounts a
where (
  select sum(h.value)
  from history h
  where h.userid = a.userid
) < 30000
```

or:

```
select a.*
from accounts a inner join (
  select userid
  from history
  group by userid
  having sum(value) < 30000
) t on t.userid = a.userid
```

**Edit**:
To apply a swcond condition for the date:

```
select *
from accounts 
where userid not in (
  select userid
  from history
  where date >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 0 day)
  group by userid
  having sum(value) >= 30000
)
```

Comment: Yes, I did, thanks. I have one issue though, I am attempting to use the first query you suggested but I want to add another condition into that inner select statement which is date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY) as I only from the sum from the current day. However, when I add this I get no rows returned. As I haven't added any rows today, the sum should equal 0 which would be less than 30000 and therefore should return to me all the user/account rows. @forpas

Comment: No you can't do this by applying there this condition. The condition `date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY)` will not sum the column `value` for rows that are not there, so it will not get as result 0.

Comment: Any way to set as zero if not there?

Comment: Fixed, I used a CASE WHEN scenario within the select statement thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Is `not exists` what you want?

```
select a.*
from accounts a
where not exists (select 1
                  from history h
                  where h.userid = a.userid and h.value >= 30000
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query:

```
select accounts.* from accounts inner join history on history.userid = accounts.userid where history.value >= 30000
```

Hope it helps you.